# Android Music Player : How to edit songs MetaData (Tags)?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-music-player

I could only retrieve song's metadata but after a lot of search, couldn't figure out how to edit it. Here's my current code:

```
public static void editTags(String pathOfSong, Context context, ActionMode actionMode)
    {
        MediaMetadataRetriever mediaMetadataRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(pathOfSong);

        String songName = mediaMetadataRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE);
        String albumName = mediaMetadataRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM);
        String artistName = mediaMetadataRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST);
        String genreName = mediaMetadataRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_GENRE);
        String year = mediaMetadataRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_YEAR);
        String trackNumber = mediaMetadataRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_CD_TRACK_NUMBER);

        //mediaMetadataRetriever.set


        Log.e("UniversalCAB", "songName: " + songName + "\nalbumName: " + albumName
                + "\nartistName: " + artistName + "\ngenreName: " + genreName
                + "\nYear: " + year + "\nCD Track #: " + trackNumber);

        mediaMetadataRetriever.release();
        actionMode.finish();
    }
```